# two cells from other table in one current cell

Tags: php, mariadb

I have a table which holds truck info . I have another table which holds driver info  (name and truck id there two of them in each trip) . I make a daily report  from the first table regarding it's current status and I want to have a cell which holds the two current drivers. When I do join on the tables I get two rows from each truck and the only difference is the name of the driver.
Is there a way to produce a single row (either PHP or SQL query) ? 
to get an idea  my current result is this :

```
Truck:DRIVER1:Date:Destination:Cargo:Remarks
Truck:DRIVER2:Date:Destination:Cargo:Remarks
```

And I want to get something like this :

```
Truck:DRIVER1 DRIVER2:Date:Destination:Cargo:Remarks
```

is that even possible ? I'm fairly new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say for example you have stored first fetched string in `$str1` and second in the second variable `$str2`.

You can now just use `ltrim()` and `rtrim()` functions as

```
<?php 
$str1 = 'Truck:DRIVER1:Date:Destination:Cargo:Remarks';
$str2 = 'Truck:DRIVER2:Date:Destination:Cargo:Remarks';
$result = ltrim($str2,'Truck:');
$result = rtrim($result,':Date:Destination:Cargo:Remarks');
?>
```

After this you get the value of `$result` as **DRIVER2**

And then you can just concatenate the result into string one as

```
$str1 = 'Truck:DRIVER1 '.$result.':Date:Destination:Cargo:Remarks';
```

And when you echo the `$str` you will get the desired output

**Output**

```
Truck:DRIVER1 DRIVER2:Date:Destination:Cargo:Remarks
```

Comment: Yes I see but  I'm getting the result in php as an array from an sql query and I iterate on this array (I have 10 trucks so its 20 results daily) , the way you describe it , as I understand is only  when I have  two rows returned ?

Comment: No you can have this for multiple rows as well.

Comment: You just need to put it together in the loop.

Comment: if you have got all the asnwer to your question can you please accept it as an answer

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because you pointed me to the right direction at least . Your solution with ltrim is about a string whereas my problem is with an array , perhaps I didn't make the question clear enough , that's my fault . The correct answer includes array_ merge with array_unique combination. Now I have another problem with that because it eliminates one of the two result set when used on an object array , but this is another question I guess.